# PHP mongodb update - $push array into array

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to update the `"coordinates"` property in the Mongo document with new events. ie. Merge the `"coordinates"` array (contains array of events) with new array of events.

What I have so far :

```
$update = array('$push' => array("coordinates" => $events));

/** @var \MongoCollection $collection */
$collection = $db->$collectionName;
$return = $collection->update($conditions, $update, $options);
if ($return === false) {
   throw new \ErrorException('Unable to update collection');
}
```

This works without throwing any error but not as intended. The above query appends the `$events` array to the `"coordinates"` array as an array.

Confusing? Maybe the image below will explain better..

[image]

Maybe someone can help me figure where I'm going wrong!

Comment: I know of one solution so far .i.e offloading the merge in php using `array_merge()` and then rewrite the `"coordinates"` with $set. But this doesn't seem like the best solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) operator

```
$update = array('$push' => array("coordinates" => array('$each' => $events)));
$return = $collection->update($conditions, $update, $options)
```

Comment: Ahh!! .. So that was what I was missing! Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: @ShalomSam Glad to have been of help!

Comment: just another question out of curiosity @user3100115 - does `$each` actually run some sort of foreach loop inside mongodb? If so i wonder which is more expensive, `$each` or `array_merge()`

Comment: Using `array_merge()` is more expensive because  `$each`  appends each element to your array and  is a native API so faster.